# Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 7, whereas the Loader expects 5 in

Tags: php, zend-guard

i am installing a script on cpanel, which includes zend i think, when i am installing i am getting this error..

```
Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 
7, whereas the Loader expects 5 in 
/home/digitalcontent/public_html/Core/Base/Init.php on line 0
```

PHP VERSION: 5.4.45

Anyone please help me out what is the issue so far...

I upload a file to check phpinfo() and found this zend engine installed

[image]

Should I update the version of Zend Engine or there is some other issue??

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one is able to answer...:\

Comment: This looks like a Zend Guard error. It has nothing to do with Zend Engine (in your screenshot) or Zend Framework (which you tagged the question with originally), other than being made by the same company. I'm afraid I've not used Zend Guard so can't really help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The Zend Guard encoded versions should be compatible with PHP run time version.
Solution:I
PHP run time version upgraded to 5.6,since this is compatible Zend guard ID 7.
Solution: II
Use Zend Guard version ID 5. 
See the compatible table from here
https://zend18.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217058968